# Does symbol visibility protect shared library from abuse/crack?

Tags: c++, c, shared-libraries

The GCC visibility feature enables us to strip off those APIs in our shared library that we don't want the customer to see. Indeed we can't use ldopen to call those hidden functions, but I wonder if this is secure enough to protect our sensitive APIs.

I just want to get some brief explanation of the reliability/security of hidden APIs in shared library, so that I can balance the effort and the risk. I asked this question only because I can't find adequate description regarding this concern in the documentations of GCC.

Please reopen this question.

Comment: I have no slightest idea. However, I can guarantee you, that if someone really wants to crack your software, he eventually will. Don't waste time on safety mechanisms - you risk, that your legit customers will suffer because of them (while unfair ones won't even see them in cracked version).

Comment: What would I do? Disassemble it; trace the program flow through the major functions; see what they do in terms of I/O and non-local data manipulation; build up an idea of their purpose through guesswork and experiment. Without function names, it would be more work, but by no means impossible. You'll need OS support (access control, restricted root access, secure key storage, etc.) to effectively make your library as user-hostile as you seem to want.

Comment: How is not having certain symbols (or all symbols, for that matter) "user-hostile"? Users shouldn't and _shouldn't need to_ reverse-engineer the program, indeed this is in most cases a breach of the EULA. While I agree that it won't delay a criminal for long, there's still nothing wrong in making their lives a bit harder. At least they have to work a bit for what they steal.

Comment: @Damon: Because, by my definition, a friendly library is one I can use however I want; in particular, one that allows me to fix bugs and remove limitations. One which prevents that (whether through obfuscation, legal shenanigans or genuine security) is not my friend, therefore hostile. Whether working around such limitations is "criminal" or "stealing" depends on your legal framework; I'm fairly sure it isn't (at worst, a breach of a civil agreement) in my country, or any other civilised jurisdiction. But I'm not a lawyer, and this isn't really the place to discuss ethics.

Comment: @Spook, I have removed the "overly broad" question of 'what would you do if you want to hack it'. Would you please reopen this question? This question arise from real-world requirement and I think it deserves a serious answer. Thanks.

Comment: I smelt a sense of hostility toward any commercial/encrypted/obfuscated/locked software. I have ever worked on my own OSS project, and also have worked for commercial companies, I have mixed feelings when judging a given software. I understand that, but could we just focus on the tech stuff and temporarily put the preference out of way?

Comment: This is not a problem of hostility, but a problem of the question. StackOverflow requires the questions to be precise, specific. How do you expect us to answer question "How reliable?"? Should we tell you: "In 68.30%"? This does not seem to be a *programming* question and that's the reason, why I voted to close it. If someone is determined enough, he *will* crack it. Doesn't that already answer your question?

Comment: I believe constructive suggestion about how to improve the way the question was asked will be much much better than close it stiffly.

Comment: I agree that it smells a bit of hostility toward proprietary software, and while the question could probably be worded a bit more precise, it is clear what the OP wants to know. There may be silly, questionable, debatable, or entirely legitimate reasons why someone would want to hide a "secret" API from the customer, but in any case it's legitimate to ask about it. Even if one may perceive the answer as trivial -- there are many questions on this site which are still a lot more trivial ("what does [strange trigraph] mean?") or worded a lot worse, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The genuine purpose for the visibility attribute is that the library doesn't expose parts of itself that aren't meant to be used directly. It makes very little difference to anyone trying to crack it. They will still have to disassemble the code, and it's not terribly hard to figure out entry points for functions (have a look yourself!). Yes, it's hard work to work your way through megabytes of code, but someone with experience will know what sort of things to look for, so can probably skip over a huge amount of code.

Comment: Also tools like "IDA Pro" figure out stack frames automatically, and generate a call graph between stack frames, including size and alignment of call parameters.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you can dissassemble the code, you can hack it. Takes maybe longer, but it can be done. A more secure protection is to run the code on some server. That's how Diablo 3 is protecting it, which works good enough. However, cracking something is a question of motivation. If your program is good enough and a hacker is determined enough somebody will crack it. You can only increase the time it takes.